# How to create check box in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am developing a site in django.I have to display a check box in templates.

I am using model form,

```
class ReportPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportPerson
        fields = ['name','first_aid','sick_bay','ambulance']
```

I have to create check box for the following fields   respectively,first_aid,sick_bay,ambulance and render in template.

Can anyone help me to create a check in django and how to design template to display the check box.

Thanks

Comment: If these fields are defined as a BooleanField in your model, then they should be rendered as checkboxes

Comment: in models they are defined as BooleanField,so how to write a template to display it in page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define you field in model as BooleanFileld - you can use

```
{{ form.first_aid }}
```

in you template

Answer (score 0):

In your forms file

```
class ReportPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_aid = models.BooleanField()
    sick_bay = models.BooleanField()
    ambulance = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = ReportPerson
        fields = ['name','first_aid','sick_bay','ambulance']
```

Then for your template you have multiple options, read on in the docs what suits your needs:
[Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)